# How can I sort a zipped list in a certain condition?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I want to sort a zipped list, from how close it is to a certain number.
Zipped Elements contain name, and a price.
one name represents a price.

```
namesList=["Bob", "Sam", "John"]
pricesList=[10,30,40]
zipped=list(zip(namesList,pricesList))
```

So it currently is

```
[('Bob', 10), ('Sam', 30), ('John', 40)]
```

and I wish these numbers are sorted, where they are closest to 27.

So they should be reordered as

```
[('Sam', 30), ('John', 40), ('Bob', 10)]
```

How is that possible?

I've tried doing

```
sorted(list(zipped[1]), key=lambda x: abs(x-pricePerPerson))
```

something like this, but it would not work.

Comment: If my English is not understandable, I will try my best to elaborate. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking the `[1]` index too early. You should only look at that member when defining the sorting *key*:

```
sorted(zipped, key=lambda x: abs(x[1]-pricePerPerson))
```

Comment: thank you so much. What is [1] supposed to mean though... and I am curious as to what variable x means. Anyways thank you so much.

Comment: I'm surprised you ask about `x`, since that is what you already used. It is the parameter that the callback (`lambda`) will get when it gets called by `sorted` for each element. Since that element is a pair (a name and a price), and the sorting should be based on the price, the callback grabs that price with `x[1]`. If it wanted to use the name for some reason, it would access it with `x[0]`.

Comment: that was a perfect answer that I wanted. Thank you so much.